# How to bring selected DataGridRow to the top of the DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to programmatically bring a selected row to the top? I'm thinking of possibly doing a workaround with the ItemsSource.

```cs
DataGridRow row = dgMapping.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;
row.IsSelected = true;
```

Comment: Do you want to [scroll the DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.scrollintoview?view=netframework-4.8), or reorder the items in it? It sounds like the former, so I'd give ScrollIntoView a shot.

Comment: I'd like to reorder if possible. I was using ScrollIntoView, but I'm trying to figure out the case of having multiple selected rows, and reordering those multiple to the top (or in this case simply bringing it to view).

Comment: is this data Grid binded with observablecollection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model add a property 'IsSelected' to bind 'IsSelected' property of DataGridRow. In the DataGrid, for ItemSource bind CollectionViewSource with SortDescription for 'IsSelected' property.